# How to disable input field using $(this) operator of type="text" with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to disable input field using $(this) operator of type="text" with jQuery?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="medical col-sm-6">
    <label class="radio">
      <input class="box" name="diabetes_complications[]" type="checkbox" value="Coronary Artery Diseases (CAD)">
      <span>Coronary Artery Diseases (CAD)</span>        
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col-sm-2">
    <input class="validate, timepicker" name="coronary_artery_diseases" type="text">
    <label for="Date">Date</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant attempts of coding this - for example WHEN / What will disable which element?

Comment: Also `label for="Date"` you do not have anything with `id="Date"`

Comment: On click of a checkbox, it should disable the input field named=""coronary_artery_diseases" using this operator

Answer (score 0):

Please post some effort next time

```js
$(function() {
  $("[name='diabetes_complications[]']").on("click",function() {
    $("[name=coronary_artery_diseases]").prop("disabled",this.checked);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="medical col-sm-6">
    <label class="radio">
      <input class="box" name="diabetes_complications[]" type="checkbox" value="Coronary Artery Diseases (CAD)">
      <span>Coronary Artery Diseases (CAD)</span>        
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col-sm-2">
    <input class="validate, timepicker" name="coronary_artery_diseases" type="text">
    <label for="coronary_artery_diseases">Date</label>
  </div>
</div>
```